# Angular only putting attribute of ng-minlength if parsed value is not nil

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch, angular-ng-if

I want to only set my attribute of `ng-minlength` when the value I parse from `data.Validation['minlength']` is not nil.

First I attempted using `ng-switch`; I had no problem doing this when handling `ng-show=true/false`. However I was unable to get it working when it was beyond just the value but also the whole declaration of `ng-minlength="..."`. Second attempt was using `ng-if` but again I was unable to get it working in the "middle" of the input.

Below is some code that works - I want the whole `ng-minlength="data.Validation['minlength']"` to only be set if the value is not nil.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" ng-model="item.foo" 
ng-minlength="data.Validation['minlength']" required/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered a simpler approach in another question of mine.

Solution by [Karaxuna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1265753/karaxuna) [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24610979/2260604)

```
<input type="text" name="foo" ng-minlength="myvar || 0" required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try **ng-switch-on**

```
 <span ng-switch on="data.Validation>
    <input ng-switch-when="null" type="text" name="foo" ng-model="item.foo" ng-minlength="data.Validation['minlength']" required/>
    <input ng-switch-default type="text" name="foo" ng-model="item.foo" required/>
</span>
```

It will create input depending on data.Validation values

However I am not sure if it will work with NULL values. It is still a good way forward.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I was hoping I could avoid using ng-switch-on, since I have 3-5 different validation points that all could be null.

Comment: You still create custom directive that will add ng-min attribute based on value that you pass.