# Simple custom directive add ng-attribute to input element

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have been trying to create a very simple directive that checks if the attribute `my-minlength` is a string (not null) and if it is; add the attribute `ng-minlength` to the input element. I feel like this should work, but it is simply not working.

My Directive

```
var app = angular.module("fooApplication", [])

app.directive('myMinlength', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if(element == "") {
                attrs.$set('ng-minlength', attrs.myMinlength);
            }
        },
    }
});
```

My HTML

```
<input type="text" name="foo" my-minlength="5" required/>
```

Edit the suggestion completely stripped from possible errors - still does not work.

```
.directive('myMinlength', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           if(true) {
                attrs.$set('ng-minlength', "5");
                $compile(element)(scope);
            }
        },
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use simpler approach:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" ng-minlength="myvar || 0" required/>
```

if scope.myvar is undefined then minlength will be 0

Comment: You have no idea how much time you just saved me - would have been nice finding out why the other method did not work though!

Comment: It will not help, for example, if you intent to add 'checked' attribute to radio-button (because even checked="false" will check it). In cases like that check for a dedicated angular directive (ng-checked in this case).

Answer (score 3):

You need to recompile your directive in order to add the ng-minlength attribute to your directive. Try this :

```
.directive('myMinlength', ['$compile', function($compile) {
                return {
                    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                       if(element == "") {
                            attrs.$set('ng-minlength', attrs.myMinlength);
                            $compile(element)(scope);
                        }
                    },
                }
            }]);
```

Comment: I use this i my form input directice. when using $compile(element)(scope); It works but i get undefined <input ....  error.

Answer (score 1):

you should use compile

```
 .directive('myMinlength', function() {
    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'A'; /* restrict this directive to attributess */

    directive.compile = function(element, attributes) {


        var linkFunction = function($scope, element, attributes) {
           attributes.$set('ng-minlength', attrs.myMinlength);
        }

        return linkFunction;
    }

    return directive;
})
```